# UIApplicationDelegate messages and performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i wrote an app for iPhone (iOS3) and everything seems to work great except UIApplicationDelegate messages when i start a thread with performSelectorOnMainThread. 
I have a long task(app. 5min) and i want to execute this task. But when i do this, it seems that my AppDelegate doesn't receive the messages like applicationWillResignActive, applicationDidBecomeActive etc. When no thread will be started, then i receive the messages :-( 
Can anybody help me to resolve this problem?

Thanks
Patrik

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i don't use the performSelectorOnMainThread performSelectorInBackground instead